# Distinguishing different linear regimes

Tags: regression, machine-learning, classification, python, scikit-learn

I have some data that I expect to look like in this figure:[image: Point in the (x, y)-plane, apparently coming from two different linear processes. Also shown are fits to the data.]

Is there a readily available algorithm that will 1) classify the two different regimes and 2) estimate the likelihood that the regimes are different?

A procedure that is implementable using [scikit-learn](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/) would be much appreciated!

Cheers!

Comment: Do you know ahead of time which points "belong" to the red line? Like, does process A make red line points and process B make green line points? OR do you need to infer the inflection point between the two regimes?

Comment: Actually, the difference in answers is probably not relevant, since I think the MARS algorithm can deal with both.

Comment: When you say "classify the two different regimes," do you mean that you'd like to classify points based on which line they're on, or are you trying to regress y on x given knowledge of the two-line structure?

Comment: @user777, I do not know which points belong to which lines - but I think the MARS algorithm is the solution! Thanks. If you put it in an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @SeanEaster, I would like to regress y on x given knowledge of a two-line structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a good application for multivariate adaptive regression splines (typically referred to by its trademarked name MARS, but available in open-source packages such as R under the name "Earth"). The idea is to extend the linear model to automatically find nonlinear trends in the data and fit linear regression models to those subsets. In your particular case, it seems like it will be straight forward to fit one regression line to each trend that we see in the data, and let the algorithm pick the best place for the location of the knots.

In general, the regression lines can be polynomials or interaction effects, but it's often sufficient to simply fit slopes with 0-order continuity at the knots.

A longer discussion can be found in *Elements of Statistical Learning.*